# How to check and convert Generic Type

Tags: c#, generics

**I have below code but not able to validate the type of displayPage.**

using System;

```
public class Page{}
public class ContentPage: Page{}
public class BaseViewModel{}

public class ChildViewModel : BaseViewModel {}

public class Base<T> : ContentPage where T:BaseViewModel{
    public void Method(){
        Console.WriteLine("in Base=>Method");
    }}
public class ChildPage : Base<ChildViewModel> {}
public class Program{
    public static void Main(){
        Page displayPage = new ChildPage();
        Console.WriteLine(displayPage is Base<BaseViewModel>);
        if(displayPage is Base<BaseViewModal>) **-> Its returning false** {
            (displayPage as Base<BaseViewModel>).Method();
        }}}
```

Comment: Can you show the class and method declaration where is `(displayPage as Base)`?

Comment: @vernou i have update my post with exact question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are in generic class like `FormBase<T>`, then you case just :

```cs
public class FormBase<T> where T: BaseViewModel
{ 
    public void Display(Page displayPage)
    {
        (displayPage as Base<T>).Method();
    }
}
```

Else, you need use covariance on the generic type. But it's possible only with delegate and interface. To do this, you need to add a interface like :

```cs
using System;

public class Page { }
public class ContentPage : Page { }
public class BaseViewModel { }

public interface IBase<out T> where T : BaseViewModel
{
    void Method();
}

public class Base<T> : ContentPage, IBase<T> where T : BaseViewModel
{
    public void Method()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("in Base=>Method");
    }
}

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Page displayPage = new Base<BaseViewModel>();

        (displayPage as IBase<BaseViewModel>).Method();
    }
}
```

In the declaration interface `interface IBase<out T>`, the keyword `out` enable the covariance for the generic type.

More information in the documentation :

> [Covariance and contravariance in generics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/generics/covariance-and-contravariance)

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the type along with `Base` class name

```
(displayPage as Base<BaseViewModel>).Method();
```

**Pseudo code**

```
using System;
            
public class Page
{
}
public class ContentPage: Page
{
}
public class BaseViewModel
{
}

public class Base<T> : ContentPage where T:BaseViewModel
{
    public void Method()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("in Base=>Method");
    }
}

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Page displayPage = new Base<BaseViewModel>();

        (displayPage as Base<BaseViewModel>).Method();
    }
}
```

here is fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/hiAPmq

Comment: @SivagnanamSubramani Please [update your post](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/74109558/edit) with the relevant code

Comment: Thanks for answer @Nitin Sawant
using System;   
 public class Page{}
 public class ContentPage: Page{}
 public class BaseViewModel{}
 public class ChildViewModel : BaseViewModel {}
 public class Base<T> : ContentPage where T:BaseViewModel{
  public void Method(){Console.WriteLine("in Base=>Method");}
        }
 public class ChildPage : Base<ChildViewModel> {}
 public class Program{
  public static void Main(){
   Page displayPage = new ChildPage();
   if((displayPaage is Base<BaseViewModal) - > it returns false{
       (displayPage as Base<BaseViewModel>).Method();
   }}}

Comment: But i need to validate the type first and then cast it.  is it possible ?
i have posted the code in above comment.
https://dotnetfiddle.net/QzN7qP